# How to select rows of a matrix except of a list of indices

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, indexing

I am going to select some rows of a data set, except of a list of indices.

For example, in a given  `data_set` I want to select all rows except for `idx = [2,3,6,11,15]`.

How can we do this in MATLAB? Is there any command or logical indexing method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this by comparing your exclusion list with a full list from `1:n`, where `n` is the number of rows. Below I've listed 2 which use this logic. I've also shown the simplest way (removing rows) but that requires an intermediate step.

I'm not sure which is more performant of these:

```
% Setup
idx = [2,3,6,11,15]; % exclusion list
M = rand( 25, 10 );  % test matrix to index (25 rows)
```

**Using `ismember` and logical indexing**

```
K = M( ~ismember( 1:size(M,1), idx ), : );
```

**Using `setdiff` to get the row numbers not listed**

```
K = M( setdiff( 1:size(M,1), idx ), : );
```

**Creating a temp matrix, then removing the excluded rows**

```
K = M;
K( idx, : ) = [];
```

---

**Error handling**

Note that the final row-removing method will produce an error if any of the rows in your exclusion list are out of bounds (e.g. if `0` was in `idx`).

The `setdiff` and `ismember` methods won't give you any errors, the presence of out-of-bounds values in `idx` are simply redundant.